# How to set Java 8 as the default in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, java-8

When I want to be using Java in Android Studio and not Kotlin, I'll inevitably want to be writing lambda expressions.

It is tedious having to do this at the beginning of every project:

- > File > Project Structure > Modules > Source & Target Compatibility > 1.8 (Java 8)

**How can we get this to happen automatically in Android Studio?**

Comment: If you are specifying the versions in gradle, as you should be, then it will automatically change those values to match `compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}`

Comment: if you are using the latest version, 3.6.3, its the default option now, you just accept it